# Modelio 4.0 Installation on Mac OS

Tags: macos, uml, diagram, class-diagram, modelio

I'm following the automatic procedure (i.e. script) described on https://www.modelio.org/forum/8-installation/3962-running-modelio-on-a-macos-x-workstation.html

Modelio 4.0 is installed in the same folder as the script.sh file.

When I type: bash fixModelio40.sh, the terminal shows the following error message:
"fixModelio40.sh: fixModelio40.sh: cannot execute binary file"

When typing "type fixModelio40.sh", the output is: "ixModelio40.sh: MacOS Alias file".

Can someone help me out?

Thanks so much,

Rob

Comment: Try `sh fixModelio40.sh`. Else show what `ls -l fixModelio40.sh` produces.

Comment: Or probably the .sh deceives you and you can just call `./fixModelio40.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rob, this way is only necessary when you don't have installed Java 8 on your machine. If you don't have it, simply you can install the Amazon Corretto Java 8 and again execute Modelio. In this [video](https://youtu.be/2gJ7mieRqJs), you can see how to do it